# Flutter, google_maps_flutter not working in IOS

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I put below code in `AppDelegate` Swift file in `XCode`.

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("some-my-api-key-from-gcp")
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

and I also enabled "Maps SDK for iOS"

and still got this error

```
** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GMSServicesException',
 reason: 'Google Maps SDK for iOS must be initialized via [GMSServices provideAPIkey:...] prior to use
```

Flutter version 3.32

IOS version 16.2

google_maps_flutter version ^2.2.3

Comment: Have you tried `flutter clean` and rebuild you app? This code seems to be fine.

Comment: @PeterKoltai Yup, and I also did remove Pod things and re flutter run again. so weird. the code from pub dev example is working fine. the only difference is mine is built with Swift and then example one uses objective-c so I am trying to change now

Answer (score 0):

did you Install the Firebase *GoogleService-Info.plist* and .json files ?

Comment: Yes I have a google service file